# React Router - route using MemoryRouter and Router together (Some links use memory while others change the url)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom` and found the `<MemoryRouter>` very useful. However, I still want many of the routes to read/write to/from the URL in the browser. How should I go about implementing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better to wrap your app in `BrowserRouter` and inside use `MemoryRouter` only where you need it

Comment: I have the same question, can you give an example, wrapping memoryrouter in browserrouter gives me Error: A <Router> may have only one child element

Answer (score 0):

For React Router v5, I think you can nest `MemoryRouter` within `BrowserRouter` where needed and detect route changes with `useLocation`.

This example code worked for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter, MemoryRouter, Switch, Route,
  useLocation
} from 'react-router-dom';

const NestedComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <p>test</p>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/browser-router">
          <MemoryRouter>
            <NestedComponent/>
          </MemoryRouter>
        </Route>
      <Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Component;
```